# What is the etymology of "blurb"?

Tags: etymology, connotation

I read:

> I would admire the blurb on the book jacket.

How is the word *blurb* related to book covers?

Answer (score 3):

According to the OED it is:

> Said to have been originated in 1907 by Gelett Burgess in a comic book
>   jacket embellished with a drawing of a pulchritudinous young lady whom
>   he facetiously dubbed Miss Blinda Blurb. (D.A.) See Mencken Amer.
>   Lang. Suppl. I. 329.

The meaning of ***blurb*** is given as:

> A brief descriptive paragraph or note of the contents or character of a
>   book, printed as a commendatory advertisement, on the jacket or
>   wrapper of a newly published book. Hence in extended use: a
>   descriptive or commendatory paragraph. Also in combinations.

However, in Britain today, the word ***blurb*** is used, in the same derisorily way, but in a wider context to include any, considered superfluous and excessive, paperwork, such as instructions, explanations, commendations etc.

Comment: By comparison, I don't think the wider context is used much in American English.

Comment: I haven't heard the wider context used much in Britain either. I hear "bumph" (or "bumf") more often used to describe excessive paperwork etc.

Comment: @LaconicDroid "Have you received all the several pages of blurb about the forthcoming conference?" That seems to me more than "a brief descriptive paragraph or note..." - per the OED definition. Or "Did you get any instructional blurb with the new heating controller?" Those seem to me the sorts of ways I might use "blurb".

Comment: @WS2 I can only say that I have never heard "blurb" used in that context or recall seeing it used in writing in such a way.

Answer (score 0):

[etymonline.com](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=blurb) says Burgess popularized it, but it was originally used a year earlier by Brander Matthews.

> used by U.S. scholar Brander Matthews in 1906 in "American Character;" popularized 1907 by U.S. humorist Frank Gelett Burgess. Originally mocking excessive praise printed on book jackets, and probably derisively imitative.